# Why does Pygame Movie Rewind Only on Event Input

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a small script in Python 2.7.9 and Pygame that would be a small display for our IT department.  The idea is that there are several toggle switches that indicate our current status (in, out, etc) , some information about our program at the school, and play a short video that repeats with images of the IT staff etc.  I have an older version of Pygame compiled that still allows for pygame.movie to function.

All of the parts of the script work, but when it gets to the end of the .mpg, the movie will not replay until there is an EVENT, like switching our status or moving the mouse.  I have tried to define a variable with movie.get_time and call to rewind at a certain time, but the movie will not rewind (currently commented out) .  Is there a way to play the movie on repeat without requiring an event, or maybe I could spoof an event after a certain length of time (note that the documentation for pygame.movie is outdated, the loops function does not work) ?

Thank you for the help!

```
import pygame, sys, os, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

pygame.display.set_caption("DA IT Welcome Sign")
pygame.font.get_default_font()
bg = pygame.image.load('da.jpg')
in_img = pygame.image.load('in.png')
out_img = pygame.image.load('out.png')
etc_img = pygame.image.load('etc.png')
present = in_img
done = False
img = 1
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
movie = pygame.movie.Movie('wallace.mpg')
movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()
playing = movie.get_busy()
movie.set_display(movie_screen)
length = movie.get_length()
currenttime = movie.get_time()
movie.play()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            movie.stop()
            done = True



        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_1:
            img = 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_2:
            img = 2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_3:
            img = 3
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_w:
            pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_f:
            pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)            
        if img == 1:
            present = in_img
        if img == 2:
            present = out_img
        if img == 3:
            present = etc_img
        if not(movie.get_busy()):
            movie.rewind()
            movie.play()
        #movie.get_time() 
        #if currenttime == 25.0:
        #   movie.stop()
        #   movie.rewind()
        #   movie.play()
    windowSurface.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    windowSurface.blit(movie_screen,(550,175))
    windowSurface.blit(present, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the code for replaying the movie out of the for loop that gets current events. Do this for that code and any other code you want to happen continuously without waiting for an event by moving the code 4 spaces to the left.

Like so:

```
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #gets most recent event, only executes code below when there is an event
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            movie.stop()
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_1:
            img = 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_2:
            img = 2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_3:
            img = 3
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_w:
            pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_f:
            pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)     
    #code below is out of the event for loop and thus executes whenever the while loop runs through       
    if img == 1:
        present = in_img
    if img == 2:
        present = out_img
    if img == 3:
        present = etc_img
    if not(movie.get_busy()):
        movie.rewind()
        movie.play()
    #movie.get_time() 
    #if currenttime == 25.0:
    #   movie.stop()
    #   movie.rewind()
    #   movie.play()
    windowSurface.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    windowSurface.blit(movie_screen,(550,175))
    windowSurface.blit(present, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I have run into this problem too while trying to do things with pygame, it seems to be a common error.

Comment: Thank you , sir! Problem solved. I forget sometimes how specific python/pygame is with its indentation formatting.